# Ansible 2.3 cannot SSH into AWS instance on Mac OS X - Permission Denied

Tags: macos, ssh, ansible, ansible-2.x

There are multiple related questions but I have had no luck with any of them. I have created an AWS Ubuntu instance with Python 2.7 installed and set it up with an existing keypair. I can successfully SSH into the AWS server from my Mac with:

```
ssh -i .ssh/id_rsa_amazon ubuntu@XXXX.com
```

where id_rsa_amazon is a PEM file with my AWS keypair private key.

When I try with Ansible 2.3 I fail with error:

```
UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Permission denied (publickey)."
```

My Command:

```
ansible-playbook -i environment/prodhost playbook/debug.yml -f 10
```

My Playbook (does a simple ps-ef command only):

```
- hosts: servers
  remote_user: ubuntu
  tasks:
    - name: Show Processes
      shell: ps -ef
      register: procs
      args:
        executable: /bin/bash
    - debug: var=procs.stdout
```

My prodhost file:

```
[servers]
XXXX.com
```

**My Ansible.cfg is empty (/etc/ansible/ansible.cfg)**

So......

When I run ansible-playbook with -vvvv option I get this horrible mess:

```
fatal: [XXXX.com]: UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false, 
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: OpenSSH_7.3p1, LibreSSL 2.4.1\r\ndebug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config\r\ndebug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *\r\ndebug1: auto-mux: Trying existing master\r\ndebug1: Control socket \"/Users/serge/.ansible/cp/242775b36f\" does not exist\r\ndebug2: resolving \"XXXX.com\" port 22\r\ndebug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0\r\ndebug1: Connecting to XXXX.com [111.111.111.111] port 22.\r\ndebug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK\r\ndebug1: fd 3 clearing O_NONBLOCK\r\ndebug1: Connection established.\r\ndebug3: timeout: 9897 ms remain after connect\r\ndebug1: identity file /Users/serge/.ssh/id_rsa type 1\r\ndebug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory\r\ndebug1: identity file /Users/serge/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1\r\ndebug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory\r\ndebug1: identity file /Users/serge/.ssh/id_dsa type -1\r\ndebug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory\r\ndebug1: identity file /Users/serge/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1\r\ndebug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory\r\ndebug1: identity file /Users/serge/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1\r\ndebug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory\r\ndebug1: identity file /Users/serge/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1\r\ndebug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory\r\ndebug1: identity file /Users/serge/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1\r\ndebug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory\r\ndebug1: identity file /Users/serge/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1\r\ndebug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0\r\ndebug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.3\r\ndebug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1\r\ndebug1: match: OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000\r\ndebug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK\r\ndebug1: Authenticating to XXXX.com:22 as 'ubuntu'\r\ndebug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file \"/Users/serge/.ssh/known_hosts\"\r\ndebug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /Users/serge/.ssh/known_hosts:41\r\ndebug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from XXXX.com\r\ndebug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521\r\ndebug3: send packet: type 20\r\ndebug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent\r\ndebug3: receive packet: type 20\r\ndebug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received\r\ndebug2: local client KEXINIT proposal\r\ndebug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c\r\ndebug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa\r\ndebug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,3des-cbc\r\ndebug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,3des-cbc\r\ndebug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1\r\ndebug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1\r\ndebug2: compression ctos: zlib@openssh.com,zlib,none\r\ndebug2: compression stoc: zlib@openssh.com,zlib,none\r\ndebug2: languages ctos: \r\ndebug2: languages stoc: \r\ndebug2: first_kex_follows 0 \r\ndebug2: reserved 0 \r\ndebug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal\r\ndebug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1\r\ndebug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519\r\ndebug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com\r\ndebug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com\r\ndebug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1\r\ndebug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1\r\ndebug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com\r\ndebug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com\r\ndebug2: languages ctos: \r\ndebug2: languages stoc: \r\ndebug2: first_kex_follows 0 \r\ndebug2: reserved 0 \r\ndebug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org\r\ndebug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256\r\ndebug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: zlib@openssh.com\r\ndebug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: zlib@openssh.com\r\ndebug3: send packet: type 30\r\ndebug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY\r\ndebug3: receive packet: type 31\r\ndebug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:4yo8VOhZ0HDRZg0TUJGeYe4Yte3+jwxlwBmoFeJq3vE\r\ndebug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file \"/Users/serge/.ssh/known_hosts\"\r\ndebug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /Users/serge/.ssh/known_hosts:41\r\ndebug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from XXXX.com\r\ndebug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file \"/Users/serge/.ssh/known_hosts\"\r\ndebug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /Users/serge/.ssh/known_hosts:41\r\ndebug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 13.55.33.196\r\ndebug1: Host 'XXXX.com' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.\r\ndebug1: Found key in /Users/serge/.ssh/known_hosts:41\r\ndebug3: send packet: type 21\r\ndebug2: set_newkeys: mode 1\r\ndebug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks\r\ndebug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent\r\ndebug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS\r\ndebug3: receive packet: type 21\r\ndebug2: set_newkeys: mode 0\r\ndebug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks\r\ndebug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received\r\ndebug2: key: /Users/serge/.ssh/id_rsa (0x7fb250c0c520)\r\ndebug2: key: /Users/serge/.ssh/id_dsa (0x0)\r\ndebug2: key: /Users/serge/.ssh/id_ecdsa (0x0)\r\ndebug2: key: /Users/serge/.ssh/id_ed25519 (0x0)\r\ndebug3: send packet: type 5\r\ndebug3: receive packet: type 7\r\ndebug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received\r\ndebug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>\r\ndebug3: receive packet: type 6\r\ndebug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth\r\ndebug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received\r\ndebug3: send packet: type 50\r\ndebug3: receive packet: type 51\r\ndebug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey\r\ndebug3: start over, passed a different list publickey\r\ndebug3: preferred gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey\r\ndebug3: authmethod_lookup publickey\r\ndebug3: remaining preferred: ,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey\r\ndebug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey\r\ndebug1: Next authentication method: publickey\r\ndebug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/serge/.ssh/id_rsa\r\ndebug3: send_pubkey_test\r\ndebug3: send packet: type 50\r\ndebug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply\r\ndebug3: receive packet: type 51\r\ndebug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey\r\ndebug1: Trying private key: /Users/serge/.ssh/id_dsa\r\ndebug3: no such identity: /Users/serge/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory\r\ndebug1: Trying private key: /Users/serge/.ssh/id_ecdsa\r\ndebug3: no such identity: /Users/serge/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory\r\ndebug1: Trying private key: /Users/serge/.ssh/id_ed25519\r\ndebug3: no such identity: /Users/serge/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory\r\ndebug2: we did not send a packet, disable method\r\ndebug1: No more authentication methods to try.\r\nPermission denied (publickey).\r\n", 
    "unreachable": true
}
```

Any reason why command-line SSH to AWS works just fine, the same code connects fine to a test Ubuntu VM on my machine, but AWS just falls over?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you please try do to something like that and passing the ssh private key and the user name variables via cli:

ansiblie.cfg

```
[ssh_connection]
pipelining = True
ssh_args = -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=30m -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no
control_path = /tmp/ansible-ssh-%%h-%%p-%%r
```

command:

```
ansible -m ping all -i <inventory_file> --private-key=~/.ssh/<your pem key.pem> -u <login user ubuntu/centos>
```

Comment: That worked XXXX.com | SUCCESS => {
    "changed": false,
    "ping": "pong"
} .   This also resolved the problem. Thankyou. Fastest fix ever for me! Still trying to figure which aspect of the config was the culprit.....

Comment: you can add to your `group_vars` `ansible_ssh_private_key_file: /home/user/id_rsa` , `ansible_connection: ssh`, `ansible_ssh_user: ubuntu`